# i had error when use configService in nestjs-redis like in the doc

Tags: nestjs

config

```
export default () => ({
  SECRET: process.env.SECRET,
  REDIS: {
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.PORT
  }

})
```

app.module

```
import { AuthModule } from './modules/auth/auth.module';
import { UserModule } from './modules/user/user.module';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import config from '../config/config'
import { RedisModule } from 'nestjs-redis'

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ load: [config] }),
    RedisModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => configService.get('REDIS') || {},         // or use async method
      inject: [ConfigService]
    }),
    UserModule,
    AuthModule,

  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

what i do wrong? i had this error

```
[Nest] 4197   - 09/20/2020, 10:08:21 PM   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Symbol(REDIS_MODULE_OPTIONS) (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the RedisCoreModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current RedisCoreModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RedisCoreModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })
 +2ms
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Symbol(REDIS_MODULE_OPTIONS) (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the RedisCoreModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current RedisCoreModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RedisCoreModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })
```

i think i did exactly what describe in nest doc
if i use just RediseModule.register(simpleJsonConfig) all work but i want this way with config service
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4):

need just add import

```
   RedisModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => configService.get('REDIS') || {},         // or use async method
      inject: [ConfigService]
    }),
```